# Android Studio Version Conflict/google maps

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

I keep getting this error when Trying to implement google maps into my project, any ideas on how to fix it?

Below is the code so far...

```
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

}
```

Answer (score 1):

These two dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
```

have to be the same version. So this would work:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.2'//using implementation instead of compile. compile is deprecated
```

Note that this applies to **all** play services dependencies. There are other dependencies (you're not using any of them though). Whatever components of play services you have installed, they have to have the same version

The actual version you set is up to you, but they all have to match. They can both be `9.0.0` for that matter

Comment: Make sure you use a version you have installed with the SDK

Answer (score 0):

Try setting both Google dependencies to the 11.6.0 (or to 11.6.2 if it's available):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'
```